# ClickOnce application update throw exception about FileAssociation

Tags: clickonce, file-association

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at System.Deployment.Application.ShellExposure.RemoveFileAssociationCLSIDInfo(FileAssociation fileAssociation, DefinitionIdentity subId, RegistryKey classesKey, String clsIdString, String productName)

at System.Deployment.Application.ShellExposure.RemoveFileAssociation(FileAssociation fileAssociation, DefinitionIdentity subId, String productName)

at System.Deployment.Application.ShellExposure.RemoveShellExtensions(DefinitionIdentity subId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String productName)

at System.Deployment.Application.ShellExposure.UpdateShellExtensions(SubscriptionState subState, ShellExposureInformation& shellExposureInformation)

at System.Deployment.Application.ShellExposure.UpdateSubscriptionShellExposure(SubscriptionState subState)

at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)

at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeCore(Boolean blocking)

at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.Synchronize()

at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.Update()

at Detechtion.Simulator.WPFApp.WindowMain.CheckUpdatesCommandExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a response to this in the MSDN ClickOnce Forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/c1c03973-7247-49ed-9eeb-cd9c83067e8b). Please provide more information about what you're doing and post your code as well.